# Custom post type template not called

Tags: posts, customization, templates

I've registered two custom post types. Now I've created a template for the post but it's not being called by WP.

Registering the post types in functions.php:

```
function create_post_types() {
    register_post_type('behandelingen', array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Behandelingen',
        'all_items' => 'All Posts'
      ),
      'public' => true
    ));

    register_post_type('medewerkers', array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Medewerkers',
        'all_items' => 'All Posts'
      ),
      'public' => true
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_types');
```

The custom post sections come through in the WP backend and I've added posts to this which seems to be working fine.

Next I've added a custom post template ("post-medewerkers.php"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to the permalink of the custom page it doesn't show "Test" but it shows the content from index.php.

Where did I go wrong? Why isn't the custom template registering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have a single.php file. When I added this and then added the single-medewerkers.php file it works perfectly. Thanks anyway!